# Parsing nested JSON and saving results as WordPress post meta

Tags: json, wordpress, recursion, post, metadata

I'm struggling with how to parse values in a nested JSON file. The JSON is generated from a `wp_remote_post` request to an external API, and it includes data that needs to be parsed and saved as postmeta for different posts within a given category. Each request is triggered when a category is edited/updated in the backend, and the item IDs (passed via PHP from $wpdb query) each correspond to an existing post in the database.

While I'm able to get the data, I have no clue how to extract/parse the "location" and "measures" values, and then save those values as postmeta for the post associated with each item ID. To complicate things further, the order of item IDs in the response is never the same as the order in the request, and for certain items there can be multiple child IDs with different measures (so we only want the measures from child IDs that match the parent/item IDs).

Here's how I'm generating the request...

**Build the request body based on template**

```
function build_json_body( $itemids ) {
    $request = '{"batch_list": [{
            "page"                  : 1,
            "page_size"             : 2000,
            "id_type"               : "item_id",
            "id_list"               : ['.$itemids.'],
            "target_geography_list" : ["local_dma"],
            "fieldset"              : ["item_id","start_time","end_time","location.zip_code","location.county_name","location.state","child_references.child_id","child_references.measures"]
    },{
                        "page"                  : 1,
            "page_size"             : 2000,
            "id_type"               : "item_id",
            "id_list"               : ['.$itemids.'],
            "target_geography_list" : ["local_cbsa"],
            "fieldset"              : ["item_id","start_time","end_time","location.zip_code","location.county_name","location.state","child_references.child_id","child_references.measures"]
    }]}';

    return $request;

}
```

**Make POST request and retrieve JSON**

```
function make_post_request($id) {

    $term_var = $_GET['tag_ID']; 
    $term_name = get_category($term_var)->slug; 

    global $wpdb;
            $data = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pm1.meta_value) FROM wp_term_relationships t INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON t.object_id = p.ID LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON (pm1.post_id = p.ID AND pm1.meta_key = 'item_id') WHERE p.post_type ='post' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND t.term_taxonomy_id = $term_var");
    if (empty($data)) return; 
        
    $request = build_json_body( $data );

    $url = "https://api.com/v1.0/items/search/batch";

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'timeout' => 45,
      'headers' => array(
        'Key' => 'djfaijfdnflaenfkn',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Connection' => 'keep-alive'          
      ),
      'body'    => $request
    ));

    $json = wp_remote_retrieve_body ($response);

}

add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'make_post_request', 1 );
```

**Nested JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "summary": {
            "count": 4,
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": 1141,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30318",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 1062,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 12.339821134389794,
                                "reach_net": 676047,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.198273562390643,
                                "eff_reach_net": 89426,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.6322835094198298,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "child_id": 1055,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 12.339821134389794,
                                "reach_net": 676047,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.198273562390643,
                                "eff_reach_net": 89426,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.6322835094198298,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "child_id": 1141,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 12.339821134389794,
                                "reach_net": 676047,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.198273562390643,
                                "eff_reach_net": 89426,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.6322835094198298,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 298,
                    "start_time": "06:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30312",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 298,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 13.685710910296048,
                                "reach_net": 734316,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 13.019577760704172,
                                "eff_reach_net": 122804,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.9785748227633993,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 3877,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30312",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 3877,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 13.255470390000001,
                                "reach_net": 726211,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 12.946919262713509,
                                "eff_reach_net": 87695,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.6006934500000016,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 5002,
                    "start_time": "06:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Floyd County",
                        "zip_code": "30161",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 5002,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_dma",
                                "reach_pct": 2.3949999818141943,
                                "reach_net": 131212,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 14.373137857978316,
                                "eff_reach_net": 13961,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 0.25483470695073507,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "pagination": {
                "page": 1,
                "page_size": 1000,
                "number_of_pages": 1,
                "number_of_items": 4,
                "number_of_children": 6
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "summary": {
            "count": 4,
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": 1141,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30318",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 1062,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 13.923677970045933,
                                "reach_net": 640729,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.205504112511724,
                                "eff_reach_net": 85192,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.8513057200313823,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "child_id": 1055,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 13.923677970045933,
                                "reach_net": 640729,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.205504112511724,
                                "eff_reach_net": 85192,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.8513057200313823,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "child_id": 1141,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 13.923677970045933,
                                "reach_net": 640729,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 8.205504112511724,
                                "eff_reach_net": 85192,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.8513057200313823,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 298,
                    "start_time": "06:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30312",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 298,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 15.129410910296048,
                                "reach_net": 696214,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 10.339577760704172,
                                "eff_reach_net": 117002,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 2.5425748227633993,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 3877,
                    "start_time": "00:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Fulton County",
                        "zip_code": "30312",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 3877,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 15.533829340000004,
                                "reach_net": 714824,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 12.947291296187263,
                                "eff_reach_net": 86320,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 1.8758217000000021,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 5002,
                    "start_time": "06:00:00",
                    "end_time": "23:59:59",
                    "location": {
                        "county_name": "Floyd County",
                        "zip_code": "30161",
                        "state": "GA"
                    },
                    "child_references": [
                        {
                            "child_id": 5002,
                            "measures": {
                                "market": "local_cbsa",
                                "reach_pct": 84.46830572687526,
                                "reach_net": 62052,
                                "eff_freq_min": 3,
                                "eff_freq_avg": 15.370369275263602,
                                "eff_reach_net": 11180,
                                "eff_reach_pct": 15.219251666046995,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "pagination": {
                "page": 1,
                "page_size": 1000,
                "number_of_pages": 1,
                "number_of_items": 4,
                "number_of_children": 6
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `WP_oEmbed::_parse_json( string $response_body )`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_oembed/_parse_json/

Comment: I'd prefer not to invoke a private core function, though I do appreciate the suggestion.